# Add #id to an ASP.NET MVC url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following on an ASP.NET MVC view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Help.Index())">
```

But I would like to add to the generated url an anchor like #privacy-policy so I would get:

```
/help#privacy-policy
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Help.Index())#privacy-policy">
```

Or you can extend the UrlHelper:

```
public static string Action(this UrlHelper helper, string action, string anchor)
{
    return helper.Action(action) + "#" + anchor;
}
```